# Wrap text on 2 lines for smallest width

Tags: css

I have a button with a flexible width. I would like to let the text wrap to 2 lines to keep the button's width as small as possible. Below are some examples.

Short words should still be wrapped to 2 lines to keep the button width small:

```
My     
Button
```

A long description should wrap to the smallest resulting width:

```
My button with 
very long text
```

A long word should just stay on one line, and the button will be larger:

```
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I've only managed to make the button wrap if I give it a width, but I want the width to be flexible. Is that possible?

My last resort would be to parse the text with js and add a `<br>` element, but if a more elegant CSS solution exists I would prefer that.

Comment: Please add some code or show what you have done to better understand the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do it like this:

**index.html:**

```
<button>
  Hello world!
</button>
```

**style.css**

```
button {
  width: min-content;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

[image]

**index.html:**

```
<button>
  Hello world! @#@#@#@#@#@#@#@#@#@#@#@
</button>
```

[image]

Give it a `min-width` if you don't want it to be too small.

Comment: This doesn't limit to a max of 2 lines, which seems to be part of the desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! I was not aware of the min-content option.